# How to show subcategories in specific format?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, custom, home, category-listing

I have want to show sub categories at home page like this:

[image]

Currently it showing as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Added content of home page with appropriate links like:

```
  <p>{{block type='core/template' template='pagayo/home.phtml'}}</p>
    <div id="CategoryWrapper">
    <div id="Category-Grid">
    <h2 class="Categories"><span class="img"> <a href="http://avprosolutions.com/index.php/procat.html"><img title="Pro Cat" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ProAudio-Main-image.png"}}" alt="Pro Cat " /><br /></a></span>&nbsp;<a href="http://avprosolutions.com/index.php/procat.html"><u><b>Pro Cat</b></u></a>&nbsp;<br><span><h3><a herf="#">Pro Audio</a>, <a href="#">Pro Audio Accessories</a></h3></span></h2>
..........
```